# How to get over constant comparison?

Tags: software-industry, salary, career-development, india, careers

I am 25. I constantly keep comparing my life with that of my peers. Most of them have moved abroad and some who stayed have gained good career progression.  Perhaps if I had chosen to move abroad I would be in a better position today.

After graduation I worked for a year in IT, then freelanced for a year, then enrolled in a post grad program in management specializing in finance. I am an associate business analyst, but I keep asking myself why I chose to stay and do a two year course instead of moving abroad. I keep thinking about the pay: in India for the role of BA, people are paid at around $10k per year but in first world countries it's around >$45k. I know the cost of living is less in India than in first world countries, but still I keep thinking I should have moved. There are other issues as well like pollution, population, etc.

How do I stop constantly comparing and focus on my job right now?

Comment: This question seems more about your motivation and psychological aspects rather than how to navigate the workplace. We can tell you to "just" focus on your job and the happy aspects in your life, and don't compare yourself to others... but that would be meaningless if you don't put it in practice

Comment: Also, a question. What is stopping you from moving abroad and/or finding a job in a country you prefer?

Answer (score 8):

It can be hard to not be envious of people who seem to have a more successful career than you, but you have to remember: you are not those people. You don't know what they've been through, or if their life would even make you happy. You may be motivated by different things than they are, and you can't really ever be certain about any of that. No matter how "successful" you are at your job, there will *always* be someone else who appears more successful - comparisons can pretty much only ever lead to disappointment.

So, how do you stop the comparisons?

The best way to avoid comparing yourself to others is to **make your own career goals,** make your own plan to obtain those goals, and then take steps to carry out your plan.

This sounds obvious, but having your own career objectives will help you to have something to focus on mentally, and will let you feel like you can "measure" your progress without needing to compare yourself to anyone else. All that matters is comparing you to where *you* want to be, not to where others are. But, before you can do that, you need to decide where you want to be.

Comment: "always be someone else who appears more successful" - I'm not normally one for TED talks, but this one is a pretty good listen for people feeling they have to judge their success against other's: https://www.ted.com/talks/mike_cannon_brookes_how_you_can_use_impostor_syndrome_to_your_benefit?language=en

Answer (score 2):

> How to get over constant comparison?

There is no comparison.  Your peers chose to move abroad and you did not.  If you want to move abroad, then do it!  You can't control what your peers do but you can control what you do.  Don't worry about things that are out of your control.  Focus on what you can control and everything should work out.

Answer (score 1):

> and probably more in first world countries

That is putting it mildly.

> How do I stop constantly comparing and focus on my job right now?

Why stop? Just do your job in such a way that it keeps that option open for the future. Add "may go to Canada" as part of your career goals and act accordingly. Your first job is a stepping stone to your next one.